# how to validate empty fields while importing data from csv files to database using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [making rules in SSIS while importing data to tables from a .csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708995/making-rules-in-ssis-while-importing-data-to-tables-from-a-csv-files)

i have to import data from a csv file which contains records of users. the problem i face here is to verify that all required field is present. I need to check that all the lines contains the USER NAME(or some other values....).if the line contains all the fields then i need to store it into a table USERS else if any of the fields are missing then it should be stored in another table ERROR_USERS.

eg:
id name password dept
1, sushil, asdfgghh, rnd
2, shakun, , rnd.

from above csv file
first record should be stored to the table USERS
and second should be stored to ERROR_USERS(as it doesn't contain the password field)